# Copy Drupal site to staging mode using cli

Tags: drupal-7, staging

I am quite new with Drupal and trying to follow the [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/copying-your-live-site-via-command-line), in order to copy a live site to a test site using cli. But, all I accomplished so far is to backup the database and modify the **.htaccess** file located in public_html/staging_directory, which I accessed through the terminal (ssh).

I would really appreciate if anyone has any feedback if I am on the right track with this link, or where to go from here as far as copying the contents of the live site.

Comment: What commands / code have you tried to copy it?

Comment: I am confused about these paths:
cp -R /path/to/drupal/ path/to/new/drupal/site

Comment: Those are just example path.

What they are saying is that you have to copy for example `cp -R /var/www/drupal /var/www/drupalTest`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The issue I am having is that I am working on this site which I didn't setup initially so the site is remotely hosted and the drupal installation is directly installed in the web root (~/public_html) and can't be copied into itself; do you have any thoughts on how would I proceed?